# Is it possible to control where texture is applied with weight paint or similar

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, weight-painting

[image]

I am using a two noise textures to create different sized cracks in a iPhone display.

I was wondering, if it is possible to control the location and the density of the smaller cracks.
Usually the cracks on a phone display are not evenly distributed and there is an area of impact with lots of small cracks.

I was wondering, if it is possible to control the location and the density of the smaller cracks?
I thought of weight paint since I used it before, to control particel symstems.

Answer (score 0):

Masks can be used to control where you want to have cracks. It's similar to weight paint but used in the shader editor.

Create one or two grey-value images (masks) and a *MixRGB* (or *Mix Shader*). Use the image texture as *Fac* value for the mix node.

Depending on your shader node setup you might need a *Math* mode (*Multiply* operation) to control the color of the cracks and the base color. Alternatively, you can different materials and transparency. The mask then controls the transparency.

Example:
[image: default cube with cracks]<sup>Default cube with cracks</sup>