# What can I do to blend this PBR material and procedural material better? -- Material test

Tags: materials, shaders, masking

I'm experiencing a few difficulties with trying to blend a PBR material and a procedural texture in a desired way. Essentially, I'm trying to place mold on an oriented strand board so that it looks true to the way it would form in real life.

The PBR material can be found here: https://ambientcg.com/view?id=Chipboard001

The procedural texture is copied from this Ryan King tutorial, (and, not that I'm trying to use this post to promote anything, can likely be found on his Gumroad page, if that would be better for ease of use): https://youtu.be/UeM_qj6Uz8U

My current attempt (below, mask included), which borrows the basic setup from an answer on a post (link below), seems to get me part of the way there, but not quite.

[image: Current attempt result, where the OSB darkens and the texture doesn't seem to map according to the mask I'm using, which is below this image]

[image: The mask that I'm currently using for the material test, which consists of a white line that feathers out into greyscale, then transitions abruptly to black]

As I understand it, the mold should be occurring the most in the white area of the mask, tapering off in the greyscale area, and not occurring at all in the black area. However, the material preview doesn't seem to support that in practice. I'm continuing to fiddle around with the node setup, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere near meaningful changes and results, and so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

If desired, I will attempt to share my node tree, however, it is a little convoluted in appearance and will not likely be legible if placed in one image. The blend file is also too large to share here using blend-exchange.com (I'm guessing because of the image textures), and so if there is another way to share that, I'm more than happy to do so.

[Is it possible to control where texture is applied with weight paint or similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216457/is-it-possible-to-control-where-texture-is-applied-with-weight-paint-or-similar)

Comment: What I in your screenshot is that the mold is strongest in the middle and quickly fading to the top and bottom (so I guess the mask in the material is rotated 90° compared to the mask image you show). I wouldn't say it's not doing what expected, just not so strongly visible. Maybe the grey gets dark too quickly? Have you setup the _Image Texture_ node containing the mask with _Color Space_ > _sRGB_? A mask should use _Non-Color_. It would have been really helpful if you also show how you have set up your material with the mask.

Comment: By the way, as a former lab technician in a company which built particle board, OSB and MDF forming machines this texture is the worst oriented "oriented strand board" I've ever seen, that yould have never passed our quality control  And the texture is called chipboard... but that's not chipboard. Sorry, rant over 

Comment: I'll have to check to see if I set it to *Non-Color* and get back to you; also, thank you for your insights! I'm kind of just working with what I have available to me for the most part, so I'll have to see if I can find or make a better OSB.